# Use association properties with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am just to set up a model in which you have news articles and topics they belong to. This is a simple association but now it get's a bit "extended". One of those topic association can be marked as the "mainTopic".

I've set up 3 tables:

- `avsn_content`, containing the newsArticles identified by `id`
- `avsn_content_topics`, containing the assoc, having `assocId`, `id`, `topicId` and a column indicating the `mainTopic`
- `avsn_topics`, containing the topic, identified by `topicId`

Furthermore, I have models for these three tables. My association model is designed as follows:

```
[Table("avsn_content_topcis")]
public class TopicNewsModel
{
    [Key]
    [Column("assocId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public NewsArticleModel NewsArticle { get; set; }

    public TopicModel Topic { get; set; }

    [Column("mainTopic")]
    public bool IsMainTopic { get; set; }
}
```

My relationship setup looks like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<NewsArticleModel>()
                    .HasMany(x => x.Topics)                        
                    .WithMany()
                    .Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("id")
                               .MapRightKey("topicId")
                               .ToTable("avsn_content_topics"));
```

I am getting this error:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> NewsArticleModelTopicNewsModel: Name: The EntitySet
>   'NewsArticleModelTopicNewsModel' with schema 'dbo' and table
>   'avsn_content_topics' was already defined. Each EntitySet must refer
>   to a unique schema and table.

Removing the `ToTable` option does not help it, so what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, found the answer right after posting this. Trying to pick the problem from the other end of the rope showed that I had to start off from the TopicNewsModel instead from the NewsModel.

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<TopicNewsModel>()
                    .HasRequired(topicNews => topicNews.NewsArticle)
                    .WithMany(news => news.Topics)
                    .Map(m => m.MapKey("id"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<TopicNewsModel>()
                    .HasRequired(topicNews => topicNews.Topic)
                    .WithMany()
                    .Map(m => m.MapKey("topicId"));
```